# Java copying buffered Image perfomance issue

Tags: java, performance, awt

he ppl!

im writing a game. since there is not much changing over time i went over to buffering parts of the board (on which the game is played) and just copying it from time to time. I have changing content in the foreground, so I still need a high fps. I also want to zoom, and here is where the fun starts: To save memory i reuse the buffers. Whenever I zoom the application lags, then runs normally.

After profiling i came with the two performance killers:

- clearing out the backbuffer (4000x4000 pixels, takes about 29 ms. To preserve transparency I use g.fillRect)
- Copying the Buffer back into the real image (which is of course not live, but again from getBufferStrategy()). This takes 300 ms, next time around about 150, then from the third frame onwards it runs smooth.

To clarify where the problem might be a bit of code. I create my own buffers in the following way:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration config = device.getDefaultConfiguration();
image = config.createCompatibleImage(width, height,Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
```

And now the part where I copy the Buffer back into the Image. Please note that I need to cut out some parts of the Buffer, this is why I went for the maximum-parameter call.

```
g.drawImage(image, vs.boardOffsetX, vs.boardOffsetY, targetWidth, targetHeight, 0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, null);
```

Finally, for my other problem: I clear out the Images as follows:

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
g.setColor(transparent);
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
```

thank you so much! been stuck on that for quite a while. And dont be shy to give me stylistic advice on my approach: Its my first honest attempt at graphics.

Thanks!

edit: The part that i really do not understand is that the exact same operation  takes very different amount of times. with only the AWT-Thread running besides my thread i get two times ~300ms, and then its down to like 10µs!!!! and that is AWFULLY fast for copying 16 millions pixels.
does anyone understand this effect? and maybe knows a way to "pre-optimize" this behaviour?

Comment: The first red flag I see is that you have a 4000x4000 pixel back buffer. Why do you need one that big?

Comment: Also, do you need to clear out your `g` instance using the width and height of `image`? That's gonna be a 4000x4000 rectangle to fill, with transparency no less. Seems like it wouldn't be necessary, just clearing out whatever rectangle lies on the screen at that time would do. Also, with the alpha set to 0 you'll have a completely opaque color. Maybe ditch the transparency.

Comment: i need the buffer since in the maximum zoom the board that needs to be displayed is just that big. i agree, its bound to be slow, but rerendering the complete content on every frame or at least every time i scroll would be slower. so yes, i need it.
only deleting parts sounds good, but complicated... will look into that later. but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It might interest you to hear that I could not really solve the problem. Instead I canceled the last zoom-step, limiting the biggest buffer to a size of 2000x2000 and eliminating the worst part of the problem. The zooming now goes quite smoothly (i measured 80ms for the first drawImage call. Thats still quite a lot, but since the view changes rapidly you dont really notice it).

In my research I also found out that i could not explicitly force java to create accelerated VolatileImages of the requiered size. That might have been the problem - god knows why. I still would like to find out though...

But to give ppl with likewise problems one final word of advice: circumnavigate.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will help you, but my app copy slightly faster with [System.arraycopy()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

```
BufferedImage tmp = (BufferedImage) img;
int[] src = ((DataBufferInt) tmp.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
int[] dst = ((DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 0, dst.length);
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. arraycopy usually has the best performance for this stuff. But I'm not certain the asker requires making copies of his image. He needs to draw it out to a Graphics context. Maybe there's some way of copying over to a pixel buffer?

Comment: the idea is good. cant get faster then that (besides actually using the graphic card). but: im trying to draw on a strategie-buffer, meaning i pretty much only have the Graphics2D-Object. So no Raster...
Is there a way to explicitly tell java that i dont want any resizing? since my image-copying really should take place pixel by pixel.